# Get value on textBox

Tags: javascript, select

I am trying get date when I selected select box on text box.

My select box.

```
{{ Form::select('destination', array(), null, array('class' => 'large', 'id'=>'destination')) }}
```

My text box.

`{{ Form::text('depart', null, array('class'=>'date', 'id'=>'date')) }}`.

And my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){    
  $('#destination').change(function(){
    var origin = $(this).find(':selected').text();

    $.get("{{ URL::route('getDate')}}", 
      {origin: origin},
      function(data) {
        var model = $('#date');
        model.empty(); 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                model.append("<input type = "text"value='"+ element +"'/>");
            });
      });
  });
});
```

This is my controller code

```
public function getDate()
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $result = [];
        $first = Input::get('origin');            

        $tables= Timetable::join('route', 'tbl_rte_id', '=', 'id')
                        ->where('rte_origin', $first)
                        ->orderBy('rte_destination', 'asc')
                        ->get(array('id', 'tbl_start'));

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $result[$table->id] = $table->tbl_start;           
        }

         return Response::json($result);
    }
}
```

When I change My javascript code and textbox to selectbox as following it worked.

```
{{ Form::select('ja', array(), null, array('class' => 'large', 'id'=>'ja')) }}        

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function($){    
  $('#destination').change(function(){
    var origin = $(this).find(':selected').text();

    $.get("{{ URL::route('getDate')}}", 
      {origin: origin},
      function(data) {
        var model = $('#ja');
        model.empty(); 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                model.append("<option value='"+ element +"'>" + element + "</option>");
            });
      });
  });
});
```

Problem is on following row

```
  model.append("<input type = "text"value='"+ element +"'/>");
```

How to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not escaping quotes in:

```
model.append("<input type = "text"value='"+ element +"'/>");
```

Either use:

```
model.append('<input type="text" value="' + element + '"/>');
```

or...

```
model.append("<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + element + "\"/>");
```

If you use an editor with syntax highlighting this should be obvious.